# Duplicate key error index on embedded document in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run this simple embedded document using mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var PageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url:String
});
var AlbumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    pages:[ PageSchema ]
});

mongoose.model('Album', AlbumSchema);
var Album = mongoose.model('Album');
var album = new Album({pages:[{url:"1"}]});
album.save(function(err, a) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

After I run this code the second time I get this Error:

```
{ 
    [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: doalbums.albums.$pages.id_1  dup key: { : null }]
    name: 'MongoError',
    err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: doalbums.albums.$pages.id_1  dup key: { : null }',
    code: 11000,
    n: 0,
    connectionId: 161,
    ok: 1 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing wrong here,but what is happening is:
An index is created for field 'pages' so it does not allow duplicates.To check this you may give this command in mongo shell `doalbums.albums.getIndexes()`(I think your DB name is **doalbums** and collection name is **albums** ) this will list all indexes in "albums".
Then remove index that is not required,using  `db.albums.dropIndex()`.This will allow duplication.
You can refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/

Comment: There was indeed some leftover index, I dropped the table and it was fixed, Thanks @dany

Comment: I'm curius how could a field take indeses by itself? I too got this err and found out that there is an index on one of the fields. But I didnt give any indexes.